# Как добиться одновременного срабатывания ховера у текста и ссылок?

Tags: html, css, css3, ссылки, hover

Приветствую всех. Есть кнопка, при наведении на которую цвет текста плавно сменяется с черного на белый, но ховер ссылок при этом срабатывает только при наведении на них. Вопрос: как правильно стилизовать кнопку так, чтобы весь текст включая обе ссылки одновременно срабатывал при наведении на нее?

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none !important;
  color: #292f38;
  -webkit-transition: color .4s ease, background-color .4s ease;
  transition: color .4s ease, background-color .4s ease;
}
.product-prev-button a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.product-prev-button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 9px 20px 11px 40px;
  background-color: #e2e6e7;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #292f38;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .17);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .17);
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}
.product-prev-button:hover {
  background-color: #330303;
  color: #fff;
}
.product-prev-button:before {
  color: #292f38;
  left: 20px;
  content: "\f053";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  padding: 0 2px;
  font-family: 'fontawesome';
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: color .4s ease;
  transition: color .4s ease;
}
.product-prev-button a {
  color: #292f38;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="product-prev-button">Назад:
  <a href="/catalog/picca/" rel="tag">Пицца</a>,
  <a href="/catalog/new/" rel="tag">Новинки</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменяйте в css

```
.product-prev-button a:hover {
```

на

```
.product-prev-button:hover a {
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none !important;
  color: #292f38;
  -webkit-transition: color .4s ease, background-color .4s ease;
  transition: color .4s ease, background-color .4s ease;
}
.product-prev-button:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
.product-prev-button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 9px 20px 11px 40px;
  background-color: #e2e6e7;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #292f38;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .17);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .17);
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}
.product-prev-button:hover {
  background-color: #330303;
  color: #fff;
}
.product-prev-button:before {
  color: #292f38;
  left: 20px;
  content: "\f053";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  padding: 0 2px;
  font-family: 'fontawesome';
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: color .4s ease;
  transition: color .4s ease;
}
.product-prev-button a {
  color: #292f38;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="product-prev-button">Назад:
  <a href="/catalog/picca/" rel="tag">Пицца</a>,
  <a href="/catalog/new/" rel="tag">Новинки</a>
</div>
```

Comment: у вас стрелочка по ховеру не подсвечивается и зачем вы еще дополнительно переопределяли стиль `.product-prev-button a` ?

Comment: Вы же сказали про текст, про стрелочку ничего не говорили. Я дополнительно ничего не переопределял, я взял весь ваш код и внес небольшое изменение в определении класса